# Beamer titlepage automatically bottom-aligned

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

The title page of my beamer presentations is automatically bottom-aligning itself when there's more than one frame in the document.

**MWE**

No problems here - the output is as expected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\titlepage
\end{document}
```

With the code below, however, the text in the titlepage is bottom-aligned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\titlepage
\begin{frame}
    Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a clear reason that this is happening? Is it likely that something's changed in the template source? Is the easiest fix likely to be re-installing the beamer package?

Comment: You can use `\maketitle` or `\begin{frame}\titlepage\end{frame}`, but not `\titlepage` alone.

Comment: Fantastic thanks. If you want to submit this as an answer I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at examples from `beameruserguide` (page 92):

[image]

and on same page

[image]

which means that `titlepage`, MUST be used inside a `\frame`, while `\maketitle` automatically adds the `frame` when it is needed.